# Python os.walk: add folder names to output

Tags: python, os.walk

I have the following script, which works well, but now I want to add the name of the folder to the output file. The script goes with os.walk into the subdirectories of the current working folder and I want to add the subdirectory folder names to the output. Preferably, I want to add only the folder name (and not the whole path) to the first line of the output file. Who can help me to edit the script? 
Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import csv
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict


def get_file_values(find_files, output_name):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(os.getcwd()):
        if all(x in files for x in find_files):
            outputs = []
            for f in find_files:
                d = {}
                with open(os.path.join(root, f), 'r') as f1:
                    for line in f1:
                        ta = line.split()
                        d[ta[1]] = int(ta[0])
                outputs.append(d)

            d3 = defaultdict(list)
            for k, v in chain(*(d.items() for d in outputs)):
                d3[k].append(v)

            with open(os.path.join(root, output_name), 'w+') as fnew:
                writer = csv.writer(fnew)
                for k, v in d3.items():
                    writer.writerow([k] + v)

get_file_values(['genes.gff.genespercontig.csv', 'hmmer.analyze.txt.results.txt'], 'output_contigsvsgenes.csv')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `os.listdir(path)` to get all subdirectory and filenames.

See: https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

`os.listdir('.')`for current directory and `os.listdir('../')` for one level up directory, for example.

`os.path.relpath('.','..')` gives you folder name of current directory.